# Java/Spring: How to retrieve password from JBOSS vault

Tags: java, spring-mvc, security

I am trying to modify out Java/Spring Framework web application to retrieve the Oracle database password from the [JBOSS Password vault](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_web_server/5.3/html/installation_guide/vault_for_jws_)

Currently, Our `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` file references a `base.oracle.db.passWord` key in the `oracle.db.properties` file.

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file:**

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="com.mycompany.myorg.myapp.datasource.EncryptedDriverManagerDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <!-- <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />-->
        <property name="URL" value="${base.oracle.db.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${base.oracle.db.userName}" />

        <!-- <property name="password" value="${base.oracle.db.passWord}" /> commented out and tried the following line-->
        <property name="password" value="${VAULT::oracle.db.password::password::}" />

        <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
             <props>
                 <prop key="MinLimit">2</prop>
                 <prop key="MaxLimit">10</prop>
                 <prop key="InitialLimit">10</prop>
                 <prop key="InactivityTimeout">2</prop>
             </props>
        </property>     
    </bean>
```

**Oracle-db.properties file:**

```
base.oracle.db.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
base.oracle.db.userName=myusercode
base.oracle.db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://oid.gtm.internal.mycompany.com:3060/ourtargetenv,cn=OracleContext,dc=mycompany,dc=com
base.oracle.db.passWord=mypassword
```

I am working under the assumption that the password value has been properly stored in the VAULT using the key `base.oracle.db.passWord`.

I was given an example of how to access the vault to get the password. The example entailed making a reference to the vault from within the `context.xml` file, not the `oracle-db.properties` file. The following was the example I was given.

**context.xml** file:

```
<Context>
    

        <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
        <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
        <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
        <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/tomcat-web.xml</WatchedResource>
        <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    

        <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
        <!--
        <Manager pathname="" />
        -->
    

        <Resource name="fds_ui" auth="Container"
                         type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
                         factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
                         driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
                         url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://oid.gtm.internal.cigna.com:3060/fdsdev,cn=OracleContext,dc=mycompany,dc=com"
                         username="myusercode”
                         password="${VAULT::oracle.db.password::password::}"                         
                                    removeAbandoned="true"
                                    removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
                                    logAbandoned="true"
        />       
    

    </Context>
```

However, given that I am not a Java developer and our Java developer doesn’t know how access the vault, I am trying to help find the answer. My attempt included modifying the above mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file to change this line

```
<property name="password" value="${base.oracle.db.passWord}" />
```

to

```
<property name="password" value="${VAULT::oracle.db.password::password::}" />
```

But when I tried this, I got an “invalid usercode/password error indicating that the password either was not properly stored in the vault (I believe it was) or VAULT reference that I added to the `oracle-db.properties` file does not work the same way as it presumably might from the `context.xml` file.

I’m well out of my comfort zone and don’t know what else to provide to help you help me but I would appreciate any suggestions.

I've looked at

[Cyberark retrieve password from vault using JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69165425/cyberark-retrieve-password-from-vault-using-java)

But this seems like it is a manual approach to retrieving the password from Cyberark. I know we use Cyberark internally. Could the VAULT statement that I was told to use within my context.xml file be a reference to some API that accesses Cyberark under the convers? I imagine that this might be the case and that I shouldn't be re-inventing functionality to do this if there is a more high level way to get it.